# How to reduce the attachment of an overly attached stray dog?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, strays

### About me

I am around 20 year old student and live in college provided hostels. I share room with one person who hates stray dogs while having some at his home.

I started getting familiar with dogs about a 1 year ago. I know almost 15 dogs around the campus and most of them are vaccinated, sterilised and localised in their respective areas. I sometimes take some dogs on walks, without leash, 3-4 in a group.

I would be leaving my college soon.

### About Ben

He is a white, around 2 year old male dog. He is friendly with lots of packs and wanders around the college but is stable in 2 hostels nearby. He is very energetic; not so keen for food as he is for playing, running and walks.

He knew my old room. When I changed it, he sniffed and found out the new one too.

### Issues

He recently started jumping onto me, in addition to licking my hands. I cannot handle both in public. I used to dodge his mouthing somehow, but pushing him down makes him more aggressive.

Also, when I am on a walk with him and some more dogs, he doesn't stop, like them, in the territory. He follows me to my room, even shows up randomly in the night at my doorstep.

Lastly, I want to reduce his attachment with me as my time to leave comes closer.

---

**Edits**

I will not be able to take him with me to my home/ job location. Also, I am looking for behavioural training which can help reduce his excitement when he sees me.

Comment: Is it possible for you adopt him, and take him with you when you move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, this is more of an ethical problem than one of training.

What outcome are you aiming for? Do you want to change the way he behaves now, or do you want to help him to prepare for the time when you leave?

In my opinion nothing could prepare the dog for your leaving. If it was attached to you only, I would suggest to involve another person and get the dog attached to that person too. But you wrote in the comment you could not take him away from the other people who adopted him. So he will get over you disappearing over time, because he has other people which care for him.

As James Jenkings suggest: you could avoid his feelings having been hurt only if you adopt him and let go him with you. But in that case, he may miss his friends  (dogs and humans) at the college instead then...

A more unethical way seems to be to shout him away from you, so he "de-attaches" from you. But I assume this puzzles the dog more than it helps him to understand you will leaving. I would not do this!